# Adding to the end of a Linked List

Tags: java, exception, linked-list, nodes

I'm having trouble with this homework problem, it compiles correctly, but I'm getting an exception that I can't figure out. Here's what's in my main method

```
MyLinkedListH1 list = new MyLinkedListH1();

  list.addLast(5);
   list.addLast(6);
   list.addLast(7);

   list.addFirst(1);
  list.addFirst(2);
  list.addFirst(3);

 list.traverse();

  list.print();
```

And the addLast method (which worked when within the main method I performed addFirst before doing a single addLast, but I don't see how that would make a difference).

```
public void addLast(int d)
{
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.x = d;
    newNode.link = null;

    Node p = first;
    if(first == null)
    {
        first = newNode;
    }
    while (p.link != null)            
  {  
        p = p.link;  
  }
        p.link = newNode;
  }
```

And the exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MyLinkedListH1$Node.access$200(Hmwkal.java:23)
at MyLinkedListH1.addLast(Hmwkal.java:50)
at Hmwkal.main(Hmwkal.java:7)
```

So it seems it's having a problem with the pointer going null. Sorry if it's something obvious, I've only been programming for a few months and linked lists aren't a strong suit of mine.

If necessary, here's the full code:

```
class Hmwkal
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       MyLinkedListH1 list = new MyLinkedListH1();

   list.addLast(5);
  list.addLast(6);
  list.addLast(7);

  list.addFirst(1);
  list.addFirst(2);
  list.addFirst(3);

  list.traverse();

  list.print(); 
   }
}

class MyLinkedListH1  
{
    private class Node 
{
      private Node link;
      private int x;
}

   private Node first = null;  

   public void addFirst(int d)
   {
       Node newNode = new Node(); 
       newNode.x = d;            
       newNode.link = first;     
       first = newNode;          
   }

public void addLast(int d)
{
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.x = d;
    newNode.link = null;

    Node p = first;
    if(first == null)
    {
        first = newNode;
    }
    while (p.link != null)            
      {  
        p = p.link;  
      }
        p.link = newNode;
      }
         public void print()
         {
            Node listNode = first;
            while (listNode != null)
         {
            System.out.println(listNode.x);
            listNode = listNode.link;
         }
      }

   public void traverse() //This AND the print might be redundant
   {
       Node p = first;
       while (p != null)
       {
       System.out.println(p.x);
       p = p.link;
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for any help ^_^

Comment: just tell your teacher: _"It works on my computer!"_

Comment: It will help to provide the code for the Node class, high lighting the line that is throwing the NullPointerException.

Comment: You could have a better title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `addLast` method is broken; it will continue to execute logic even after we've established that the node we start on is `null`.

What you want to do is have a complete `if-else` case, in which the `else` branch covers the traversing of the list:

```
public void addLast(int d) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.x = d;
    newNode.link = null;

    if(first == null) {
        first = newNode;
    } else {
        Node p = first;
        while(p.link != null) {
            p = p.link;
        }
        p.link = newNode;
    }
}
```

This now has the behaviors that one wants; if there are no nodes in the list, and we are adding to the last element, we will add our element in as if it were the last one being added in.  If the head element is not null, we will traverse the list, and insert it at the end.

Comment: That's not true at all, and I feel that it could be made a bit more apparent by pushing `p` into the `else` clause.  If `first` is `null`, we only assign the reference we create to it.  If it isn't, then we're okay.

Comment: Well that worked, so thanks so much! :D A quick question though to help me understand the code. Why does this code work to addLast (I only called this method once if that's relevant)?

**Sorry, trying to tidy this up**
`public void addLast(int d){
  Node newNode = new Node();
  newNode.x = d;
  newNode.link = null;
  
  Node p = first;
  if(first == null)
  {
   first = newNode;
  }
  while (p.link != null)            
      {  
      p = p.link;  
      }
      p.link = newNode;
   }`

But with the problem above I got an exception?

Comment: That code's about 95% intelligible in the comment box.  But, the simple answer is:  you don't get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yeah, it came out pretty messed up. Regardless, I appreciate the correct answer. I think I'll sit down with my teacher to review nodes because my understanding of what all of the code is doing is pretty weak. Thanks a million though!